# How to test existence of table column on a linked server

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server 2012, I need to test for the existence of a column that's in a table on a linked server.

I have been trying different variations of the statement below but, `IF EXISTS` always return false, even when the column does exist. Some playing around shows that `OBJECT_ID(N'MY_DB.dbo.My_Table')` is always NULL.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [MY_SRVR].MY_DB.sys.columns WHERE
    (name = N'My_Column')
AND
    (OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID(N'MY_DB.dbo.My_Table')))
...
```

The query works fine when run on the server the database is located on, but fails when run where the database is on a linked server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work.

```
IF EXISTS 
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM [MY_SRVR].MY_DB.sys.columns c
    join [MY_SRVR].MY_DB.sys.tables t on t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
    WHERE c.name = N'My_Column'
        AND t.name = N'My_Table'
)
```